# how to implement shortcodes in pages or blog?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using php framework laravel and I would like to implement shortcodes.

Does anyone have a suggestion how to go about implementing shortcodes that could be inserted by user into a page or blog post.

Example, lets say I would like to have a shortcode for gallery that has some images, something like

> [gallery=id]

which would then display that particular gallery. Ofcourse I have gallery model and gallery & images tables.

My first thought is that I would have to scan the content of the page/post and look for shortcode and when I find a particular shortcode, then what? What do I insert instead of it?

I can't insert php code that loops through the gallery and produces output. I guess the best way to do it would be to run a function that returns complete html code that I insert instead of the shortcode.

Is it possible to return a view from a function and insert the result into a page/post?

Comment: What exactly do you want? to display a gallery page that only a certain user can access?

Comment: I want the admin to be able to use a shortcode in this example gallery shortcode, and when visitors would visit a page that uses this shortcode, page would render a gallery with images. It will ofcourse be visible to all users. Note: I am not using Wordpress, I am using Laravel and want to implement this my self

Comment: @Maxlight You can use my library Shortcode for that: https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode .

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, I'm assuming you want to insert this into content blocks stored in a db or something, not in your exiting view files.

Assuming you want inject the text into your view for display, you could allow content creators to use a templating format like mustache  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mustache_%28template_system%29) with server side callbacks/helpers/partials (in the view) to populate your own custom tags with dynamic content (gallery links in this case).

**Main Points**

1. I'd stick to a basic well known templating format like
   mustache  for this.  In laravel, allow to Blade templating notation, it sounds like you want for this case to register a `Blade::directive`: https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#service-injection.
2. I'd try to use an existing library if one such exists before
   attempting to create your own short-tagging markup parsing /
   callback paradigm.  Blade has functions and methods handle such callbacks.

#2 is not necessary, but highly recommended, but #1 should be considered near religious.

> UPDATE: as point out in other answers, Laravels built-in templating Blade, has this functionality, so stick to it's format and functionality.

Here's my suggestion (in pseudo-laravel/php):

- Assume your marked up content from model pulled into the controller is in `$content['blade_markedup_content' => 'here is my new gallery: @gallery(1)']` to be passed to the view.
- Add a Blade directive `@preprocess()` to and in the template/view use `<p>@preprocess($blade_markedup_content)</p>` in place of just substituting raw `<p>{{$blade_markedup_content}}</p>`.
- In the respective callback function for the  `@preprocess()` directive

  - Instantiate a new `$my_compiler = new BladeCompiler();`
  - Register to this new blade compiler directives to handle the  like `@gallery(1)` you put in your `blade_markedup_content`
  - return from the `@preprocess()` with `$my_compiler->compileString($blade_markedup_content)`;
- Viola... In theory, this should result in a parsed and substitute string from `@preprocess($blade_markedup_content)` in the original template.

Comment: I am not using Wordpress, I am using Laravel and want to implement this my self for my application. As far as I know wordpress plugins do not work with Laravel.

Comment: @Maxlight Soorry, you're post was tagged wordpress.

Comment: No problems, I tagged it wordpress expecting perhaps some wordpress developer to give some advice how this could be implemented in another framework, thanks anyways! :)

Comment: @Maxlight the same logic applies though--See my update

Comment: Ah, I read your post wrong, you want links to other entities/resources, not styling

Comment: @Maxlight changed my answer to reflect what you were actually asking--I think

Comment: Thanks I saw it, Laravel uses blade templating system, it's integrated into it so I can't use mustache. What I want to implement is a shortcode that can be entered by the admin in the backend when creating a new page/blog post. I would then need to scan the content of the page/post before outputing it to find any shortcodes and then delete the shortcode and insert the actual stuff, in my example above I would insert a gallery with images, this then would be displayed to the end user, they would never get to see the shortcode it self. I am just wondering what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Sure, Blade format  is a pretty close implementation Mustache, they must have the abitlity to put partials, and callbacks.   I see @Paras answered with just that, functions that implement the paritals (sub-view) and other types of helpers/callbacks.

Comment: well partials are used inside a blade template, that is where the content is rendered, I need to process stuff before it reaches the blade since doing logic stuff for the shortcode in the blade template is not ideal way to implement this. I was thiking a little bit and perhaps the best way is to scan the content before its sent to the blade, search for shortcode, remove the shortcode, call appropriate function for the shortcode and have that function return the html code that is inserted in the original content replacing the shortcode. This content can now be sent to the blade template.

Comment: You'd want directives for that, not partials in this case. You register callbacks as a directive to replace the tag with whatever: https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#service-injection

Comment: This is how Laravel calls the blade template:

`$page = Page::find(page_id)->first();
$content = $page->content;
return view('page.show', compact('content'));`

I need to process the content before it even reaches the blade template, it's too late to do it there, I do not see how using partials, or layouts, or anything else would help inside the template on the unprocessed content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133591/discussion-between-maxlight-and-ray).

Comment: I see, the text is in the compacted content array, passed to the template. So it's injected, not evaluated.

Comment: @Maxlight were you able to get this working?  Did the approach in our chat work (added it to my answer)

Comment: Hi I found a package that allows me to do this [gallery id=1 someattribute="whatever"] so I decided to use that

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of "shortcode" you want, there are numerous options here:

1. [Blade Directives](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#extending-blade)
2. [Blade Layouts](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#template-inheritance)
3. [Blade Sub-Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views)
4. [Blade Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#stacks)